# What MAME UI frontends are available for Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, games, gui

I have installed Mame via SDLmame but have so far failed to successfully install any decent GUI that enables categorisation of games, favouriting, or preview screenshots. I have many hundreds of ROMs.

- Gnome Video Arcade will not read my ROMs from an external hard drive,
  even when they have been configured correctly in ~/.mame/mame.ini
- [Lightning](http://lightningmf.neoname.eu/) looks interesting but crashes when trying to build a
  database of my ROMS
- [QMC2](http://qmc2.arcadehits.net/wordpress/) fails to install due to missing
  dependencies
- GMameUI also fails to install on Ubuntu 12.10

Any guidance appreciated! Thanks

Comment: **GMameUI** fails probably because its last version is from 2009, and it wasn't ported to GTK3. It was removed from the 12.04 repositories, and probably never made it to 12.10.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried Gnome Video Arcade, and it also didn't list any ROMs. After investigating, it turned out that one of my ROMs was corrupted, and that prevented GVA from showing *any* ROMs at all!

So, care to do a little test?

- Backup your current MAME config/rom folder:

  ```
  mv ~/.mame ~/.mame.bak
  ```
- Recreate it with default settings:

  ```
  mame
  mkdir ~/.mame/roms
  ```
- Copy a *single* game to the default roms folder, and test it with no launcher:

  ```
  cp /path/to/roms/for/example/rastan.zip ~/.mame/roms
  mame rastan
  ```

If that works, great!

Now delete (or backup) the GVA database so it is re-created from scratch, and test it:

```
    rm -rf ~/.local/share/gnome-video-arcade
    gnome-video-arcade
```

I did this, and it worked nice. Then it was a matter of finding and deleting th offending ROMs and rebuild my MAME settings.

Answer (score 2):

The new [GNOME Games](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Games) app is a frontend for many games.

Unfortunately, it's not been packaged for Debian or Ubuntu yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround to avoid Lightning MAME Frontend (lightningmf) crashes when building database.

Into the mame.ini file, you must set the "numprocessors" entry with a numeric (integer) value, not "auto" as it set by default.

---

Explanation...

The script `/usr/share/pyshared/lightningmf_pk/__init__.py` generates following error when building database
because of a badly formatted XML file created in `/tmp`:

```
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/lightningmf_pk/__init__.py", line 213, in parse_elements
event, root = doc.next()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1266, in next raise e
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

The temporary XML file starts with those two lines who make the parser confused:

```
While parsing $HOME/.mame/mame.ini:
Illegal integer value for numprocessors: "auto"; reverting to auto
```

Answer (score 1):

I am playing MAMEUI 32 0.146 fluently with a old Laptop C500 ( Pentium M )
emulating the windows ver. with wine. :) the roms work better than linux mame for me [snap shot of neogeo game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjMnR.jpg)

[wine runs win mame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hddi2.png)